# Calculating distance of all the points in a region with each other

Tags: matlab, matrix, distance

I have a region with about 144 points. What i want to achieve is to measure the distance of a point with all others and store it in an array. I want to do this for all the points. If possible i would like to store this data in such a manner that there in no repetition. And i should be able to make queries like- All the distances between all the points without repetition, sum of all the distances for point no56 etc.

I have a 3*144 array with two columns storing the coordinates of the points.

Comment: I just noticed this question, and wanted to give a link to [this answer with a comparison of three methods for computing pairwise distance in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19456458/2778484). The other question is terribly confusing, but the answer addresses pairwise distances, the last method in any dimension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible solution (I am not really clear with what you mean by no repetition, though):

```
 X are your points with coordinates x = X(:,1), y = X(:,2)


 dist = sqrt(bsxfun(@minus,X(:,1),X(:,1)').^2 + bsxfun(@minus,X(:,2),X(:,2)').^2)
```

so

```
dist(i,j) is the euclidean distance between i and j
```

of course the matrix is symmetric. You can easily reduce the complexity involved.

Comment: By repetition i meant that distance form point A to B is the same as for B to A, so it should not be accounted.

Comment: @Vikram, Right, the matrix is indeed symmetric. By the way, for small number of points (as 144), probably this more-brute-force-like approach is somehow faster than smarter methods. Just give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your array is `A`, where each column stores the coordinates of a single point. To obtain the combinations of all point pairs (without repetitions), use [`nchoosek`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html):

```
pairs = nchoosek(1:size(A, 2), 2)
```

Then calculate the [Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) like so:

```
dist = sqrt(sum((A(:, pairs(:, 1)) - A(:, pairs(:, 2))) .^ 2, 1))
```

If you have the [Statistics Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/index.html) installed, you can use [`pdist(A)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html) instead for the same effect.

Comment: I have the pdist function. What does the [4] in [pdist(A)][4] accounts for?

Comment: @Vikram it's just a typing error (I tried to make a hyperlink to the `pdist` official documentation). It should be `pdist(A)`. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the statistics toolbox, and if you have all your data in the array X, then

```
D = pdist(X)
```

gives all the pairwise distances between all points in X.

Comment: Easiest solution if you can live with a triangular matrix instead of a symmetric distance matrix (although [`squareform`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/squareform.html) can get you all the way). +1  For reference, see [this other post's answer for a comparison of `pdist` and other "manual" solutions"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19456458/2778484).