# Find the distance from one point in a matrix to all other points in a matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vectorization, bsxfun

I have a matrix `a` and I want to calculate **the distance from one point to all other points**. So really the outcome matrix should have a zero (at the point I have chosen) and should appear as some sort of circle of numbers around that specific point.

This is what I have already but I cant seem to get the correct outcome.

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]

for i = 2:20
    a(i,:) = a(i-1,:) + 1;
end

N = 10

for I = 1:N
    for J = 1:N
        dx = a(I,1)-a(J,1);
        dy = a(I,2)-a(J,2);
        distance(I,J) = sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2)
    end
end
```

Comment: Maybe I'm just confused, since other people seem to understand what you are asking.  However, a matrix does not have "points" unless you are referring to elements, in which case the answer is simply `abs(a-a(i,j))`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating distance of all the points in a region with each other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483468/calculating-distance-of-all-the-points-in-a-region-with-each-other)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is what i was looking for, but thanks for all the suggestions.

```
A = rand(5, 5);
select_cell = [3 3];
distance = zeros(size(A, 1), size(A, 2));
for i = 1:size(A, 1)
    for j = 1:size(A, 2)
        distance(i, j) = sqrt((i - select_cell(1))^2 + (j - select_cell(2))^2);
    end
end
disp(distance)
```

Also you can improve it by using vectorisation:

```
distances = sqrt((x-xCenter).^2+(y-yCenter).^2
```

Comment: What was wrong with my solution, which you had previously accepted? The example in your question shows distance from each point to each other point.  Of course this solution is simple if you just want a small part of the solution...

Comment: The loops in this answer don't even make sense, and the vectorized answer does not go with the looped answer.  What are x and y in a 5x5 matrix??  And `A` is not even referenced in the loop!!!

Answer (score 12):

Your `a` matrix is a 1D vector and is incompatible with the nested loop, which computes distance in 2D space *from each point to each other point*.  So the following answer applies to the problem of finding all pairwise distances in a `N-by-D` matrix, as your loop does for the case of `D=2`.

### Option 1 - pdist

I think you are looking for [`pdist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html) with the `'euclidean'` distance option.

```
a = randn(10, 2); %// 2D, 10 samples
D = pdist(a,'euclidean');  %// euclidean distance
```

Follow that by [`squareform`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/squareform.html) to get the square matrix with zero on the diagonal as you want it:

```
distances = squareform(D);
```

### Option 2 - bsxfun

If you don't have `pdist`, which is in the Statistics Toolbox, you can do this easily with `bsxfun`:

```
da = bsxfun(@minus,a,permute(a,[3 2 1]));
distances = squeeze(sqrt(sum(da.^2,2)));
```

### Option 3 - reformulated equation

You can also use an alternate form of Euclidean (2-norm) distance,

```
||A-B|| = sqrt ( ||A||^2 + ||B||^2 - 2*A.B )
```

Writing this in MATLAB for two data arrays `u` and `v` of size `NxD`,

```
dot(u-v,u-v,2) == dot(u,u,2) + dot(v,v,2) - 2*dot(u,v,2) % useful identity
%// there are actually small differences from floating point precision, but...
abs(dot(u-v,u-v,2) - (dot(u,u,2) + dot(v,v,2) - 2*dot(u,v,2))) < 1e-15
```

With the reformulated equation, the solution becomes:

```
aa = a*a';
a2 = sum(a.*a,2); % diag(aa)
a2 = bsxfun(@plus,a2,a2');
distances = sqrt(a2 - 2*aa);
```

You might use this method if Option 2 eats up too much memory.

### Timings

For a random data matrix of size 1e3-by-3 (N-by-D), here are timings for 100 runs (Core 2 Quad, 4GB DDR2, R2013a).

- Option 1 (`pdist`): 1.561150 sec (0.560947 sec in `pdist`)
- Option 2 (`bsxfun`): 2.695059 sec
- Option 3 (`bsxfun` alt): 1.334880 sec

Findings: (i) Do computations with `bsxfun`, use the alternate formula. (ii) the `pdist`+`squareform` option has comparable performance. (iii) The reason why `squareform` takes twice as much time as `pdist` is probably because `pdist` only computes the triangular matrix since the distance matrix is symmetric.  If you can do without the square matrix, then you can avoid `squareform` and do your computations in about 40% of the time required to do it manually with `bsxfun` (0.5609/1.3348).

Comment: For the `bsxfun` version, if speed is important use `da = bsxfun(@minus,a, reshape(a.',1,size(a,2),size(a,1)));`

Comment: I think that the question itself is a duplicate, but the mere effort here, in the face of ungratefulness, deserves a big +1.

Answer (score -3):

IMPORTANT: data_matrix is D X N, where D is number of dimensions and N is number of data points!

**final_dist_pairs=data_matrix'*data_matrix;**

**norms = diag(final_dist_pairs);**

**final_dist_pairs = bsxfun(@plus, norms, norms') - 2 * final_dist_pairs;**
Hope it helps!

% Another important thing,
**Never use pdist function of MATLAB**. It is a sequential evaluation, that is something like for loops and takes a lot of time, maybe in O(N^2)

Comment: Your code won't run as written, should the second line read `norms = diag(dist_pairs)`?

Comment: It was a typo, I thought the person could make atleast this much out of it!