# How can this code be vectorized in MATLAB? Which kinds of code can be vectorized?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Say, for example, I have a piece of code that finds the `distance` between each pair of `locations`:

```
k=1;
for i=1:size(location,1)
    for j=1:size(location,1)
        distance(k,1)=i;
        distance(k,2)=j;
        distance(k,3)=sqrt((location(i,1)-location(j,1))^2 + (location(i,2)-location(j,2))^2);
        k=k+1;
    end
end
```

The output must be these exact same 3 columns, first for location number 1, second for location number 2, and third for the distance between them.

How can I vectorize this, so that it finishes in O(n) time (can it be done faster?) instead of in O(n^2) time like in my code?

Comment: This can never be order O(n). You could maybe beat O(n^2) by accounting for the inherent symmetry in the problem. But also, the goal of vectorization in MATLAB is not to reduce the algorithmic complexity, just the efficiency of the running when implemented in MATLAB i.e. optimizing code to play to MATLAB's strengths. In your case have a look at the function `pdist`. I suggest you change the title of your question to be less general.

Comment: I take it back, you can't beat O(n^2). But you can certainly beat a nested `for` loop using vectorization. `pdist` already does it for you. You could use `bsxfun` to generate your `i`s and `j`s if you don't have `pdist`. This has been answered here many times before: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19456458/1011724

Comment: I'm closing this as a duplicate. Your title question "Can every code be vectorized" is opinion based and too broad. Your actual question is an exact duplicate aside from your misunderstanding that vectorization is reducing the complexity, not just the run-time efficiency.