# Fast way to thin 2D point data

Tags: matlab, 2d

I have a set of 2D data in the format [X Y] and am going to thin them based on a certain distance threshold, i.e. if points are very close less than a threshold, one is eliminated. This process continues until the distance between any two points is bigger than the threshold. I developed a code to do that but it is very time consuming. I am wondering if there is a better way of doing this in Matlab.

Comment: Please post your code. We can eventually find the bottlenecks and suggest improvements. Also, have to tried you profile it ?

Comment: Here's an approach. 1. find points (you have it already). 2. resize the "matrix" that is created by these 2D data points using `imresize`. 3. find the points again with their adjusted positions. if there is only one point instead of two then the thershold was crossed. The `imresize` function handles in a sense act as the threshold .

Comment: @bla, interesting idea, but this would not just thin the data out, but also force them onto a grid.

Comment: the way I see it, defining a threshold is defining a grid of some size.

Comment: When two points are to close to each other, is there a specific rule which to remove?

Comment: How many points do you have and how many are typically left after thinning?

Comment: The only rule is the distance to make sure all points left aren't any closer than the threshold.

Comment: Typically around %10 of all point are removed. The size of points depends on the project size. For example for a small-size area it could be 50000 points.

Comment: This is the code I am using

Comment: function [E_temp,N_temp]=thin_pts(E,N,dist) 

    E_temp=[];N_temp=[];

    while(~isempty(E)) 

        E_diff=E(1)-E;N_diff=N(1)-N;dist_EN=sqrt(E_diff.^2+N_diff.^2);

        dist_EN_idx=dist_EN<dist;

        E_temp=[E_temp;E(1)];

        N_temp=[N_temp;N(1)];

        E(dist_EN_idx,:)=[];

        N(dist_EN_idx,:)=[];

    end

Answer (score 0):

Just to give a simple idea to have something better than pairwise comparing.

Let d be the minimal distance you want to achieve. Create a grid of squares with edge length `sqrt(d)`.

1. Put each point into it's square. For each square keep only one point. If a square has two points in it their distance is less than `d`
2. You have some remaining points with distance less than d, but for each point you only have to check the 8-neighbourhood of surrounding squares.

Comment: Daniel, Sounds a good idea but I don't know how to implement it. Do you have any similar code available so that I can test it and compare to mine?

Answer (score 0):

You can caluclate the distances as described here

[Calculating distance of all the points in a region with each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483468/calculating-distance-of-all-the-points-in-a-region-with-each-other)

so simply copy pasting his answer:

```
 X are your points with coordinates x = X(:,1), y = X(:,2)
```

dist = sqrt(bsxfun(@minus,X(:,1),X(:,1)').^2 + bsxfun(@minus,X(:,2),X(:,2)').^2)

this gives you a matrix with all the distances between each point. With `find(dist<thres)` you get the positions of distances which are below your thres. Then use `ind2sub` to identify the position for the data you want to remove

Comment: Hi horseshoe, I tried to test your method but stuck at ind2sub. How can I get the position of points to remove using ind2sub? Thanks